# Color Depending On Percentage

Tags: java, colors

Hey guys im making a healthbar.
It uses percentages from 100% to 0% for the health representation.
I want that it changes color depending on how much health is left.
100% must be green and 0% must be red.
Is there some kind of formula or function that i can use/make to do it automatically?? 
The colors are in the following format: `0xFFRRGGBB`

Comment: Color is meaningless unless you have a Graphics object to draw the colors on.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: since the colour you're describing is a triad of red, green, and blue, describing the colour as one percentage doesn't make too much sense. You need more data points for a suitable conversion. For example, what percentage value does white (all FFs) sit at? What about black (all 0)? What about primary blue? Why is your specification of orange is 50%, when this is (for example) 100% red, 50% green, and 0% blue?

Comment: Why 0% and 100% because im making something where 0% is dead so red and 100% health alive so green. 

And yes i can draw my drawing function takes in 0xAARRGGBB
so Alpha Red Green Blue.. And i dont need transparance so 0xFFrrggbb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need a gradient from green to red, then something like this:

```
// import java.awt.Color;

static Color HealthToColor(double percentage) {
    if (percentage > 1) {
        percentage = 1;
    }
    else if (percentage < 0) {
        percentage = 0;
    }
    int red = (int)(255.0 * (1 - percentage));
    int green = (int)(255.0 * (percentage));
    int blue = 0;
    return new Color(red, green, blue);
}
```

If you need as a percentage, obviously divide the health by 100.

- HealthToColor(1) // -> java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]
- HealthToColor(0) // -> java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
- HealthToColor(0.5) // -> java.awt.Color[r=127,g=127,b=0] (this is olive, not orange)
- HealthToColor(0.1) // -> java.awt.Color[r=229,g=25,b=0] (this is orange-red)

Comment: Thanks a lot
@kjhf
I needed a small change to the code. I needed to change return type to int and the return line to 
`return new Color(red, green, blue).getRGB;`